# Highlight search terms on a Django/PostgreSQL search results page

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, full-text-search

How can I create a search results page in Django 1.11, using [PostgreSQL full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/), where the terms searched for are highlighted?

Comment: Let me make sure that I understand what you're asking for. Basically, like in this screen right here, if you're in Chrome and you do cmd/ctrl + f and search "ask" and get a bunch of things yellow highlighted. You want that same appearance, but you want the appearance to be a list view?

Comment: Correct. What is discussed in this article: https://alistapart.com/article/searchhighlight

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though Django doesn't support [ts_headline](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE) feature from postgresql, You can manually apply it as a `Function` on a `QuerySet` to annotate:

---

We need additional function to operate with django ORM. Here is a sample for ts_headline. [original_source for this sample function is linked [here](https://github.com/damoti/django-tsvector-field)]

Headline function sample:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.search import Value, Func


class Headline(Func):
    function = 'ts_headline'

    def __init__(self, field, query, config=None, options=None, **extra):
        expressions = [field, query]
        if config:
            expressions.insert(0, Value(config))
        if options:
            expressions.append(Value(options))
        extra.setdefault('output_field', models.TextField())
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)
```

Using the above function you can use it on a QuerySet to annotate

### Example Model Definition

```
class Video(Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Title")
```

---

### Steps for getting highlighted search results on model title

1. Filter and get the QuerySet needed to annotated
2. Annotate using Headline function
3. Get Values of your document

---

**Filtering Objects**

```
Video.objects.filter(filter_query)
```

*filter_query* is a Q() over title
filter_query = Q(title__contains=term)

---

**Annotation with Headline data**

```
Video.objects.filter(filter_query).annotate(title_highlight=Headline(F('title'), text_search_query))
```

*ts_headline* directly take the input from the document rather than from ts_vector, So we have to pass the information about which field it should access and what SearchQuery it should perform on it.

*text_Search_query* is SearchQuery Object with same input as the filter_query
text_search_query = SearchQuery(term)

Now after annotation, this queryset with include a extra field in all objects called **title_highlight** which would contain the result you wanted like:

`these <b>loans</b> not being repaired`

---

**Get the values from the annotation field**

using `values_list` over the QuerySet you can get the values from these annotated fields.

final code:

```
Video.objects.filter(filter_query).annotate(title_highlight=Headline(F('title'), text_search_query)).values_from('title','title_highlight')
```

Comment: Nice. If you want the whole string, not just the extract, use `Headline(F('title'), text_search_query, options='HighlightAll=TRUE')`

Comment: awesome content. really helped me. Thanks

Comment: This answer is no longer current. As of Django 3.1, there is a SearchHeadline class, via `from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchHeadline`.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.1, there is now a [`SearchHeadline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchheadline) class which makes this task much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks about Django 1.11. Things have changed, as there is a `SearchHeadline` class in Django 3.1.

I've not noticed much code on this in Stack Overflow, so consider the following:

1. Assume that models.py contains an Article model. It has two `TextField`s ('headline'/'content') and a `SearchVectorField` for the content:

   ```
   from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchVectorField, SearchHeadline
   from django.db.models import F, Q

   class Article(models.Model):
   headline = models.TextField()
   content = models.TextField()
   content_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)
   ```
2. In your console/terminal, the following code will work:

   ```
   query = "book"

   Article.objects
   .annotate(v_head=SearchHeadline(F("content"), query))
   .filter(content_vector=query)
   ```
3. There are two parts to the above - the annotation using `SearchHeadline` to annotate a v_head 'column', then the filter itself against the query for "book".
4. Assuming that the text was *"Lorem ipsum book lorem ipsum"*, the output will be:

   > Lorem ipsum <b>book</b> lorem ipsum.

You can see [other similar code on Github](https://github.com/search?q=SearchHeadline&type=code).